# Autofill a parameter before validation

Tags: swagger-ui

Please help me to figure out how to autofill a parameter when I press the Execute button on Swagger-UI?
I know how to modify a parameter in the request with `requestInterceptor`, but I don't like this approach, since the parameter displayed on the screen and the parameter in the actual request look different.

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

openapi.yaml:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Swagger Petstore
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: https://petstore.swagger.io/v2
paths:
  /pet/findByTime:
    get:
      parameters:
      - name: time
        in: query
        description: Should be auto generated when I press Execute button
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: successful operation
```

Here is my code:

```js
// My plugin
const MyWrapActionPlugin = function(system) {
  return {
    statePlugins: {
      spec: {
        wrapActions: {
          validateParams: (oriAction, system) => (arr) => {
            // TODO: Autofill time parameter with the current time
            if (system.getState().getIn(['spec', 'meta', 'paths', arr, 'parameters', 'query.timestamp.hash--309052266', 'value'])) {
              system.getState().setIn(['spec', 'meta', 'paths', arr, 'parameters', 'query.timestamp.hash--309052266', 'value'], 'test')
            }
            return oriAction(arr)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "openapi.yaml",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis
    ],
    plugins: [
      MyWrapActionPlugin
    ]
  });

  window.ui = ui;
};
```

`validateParams` action happens whenever I press the Execute button, so I think that’s where the logic needs to be.
My approach is to find the parameter with `getIn()` and modify its value, but it doesn't work and I am not sure if it is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out myself:

```js
const MyWrapActionPlugin = function(system) {
  return {
    statePlugins: {
      spec: {
        wrapActions: {
          validateParams: (originalAction, system) => (pathMethod) => {
            const date = new Date()
            const newValue = date.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', '')
            // change parameter value
            system.specActions.changeParam(pathMethod, 'timestamp', 'query', newValue, false)
            return originalAction(pathMethod)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```